# Why is MeasuredHeight always 0, and how can I get the value?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm trying to apply an animation to collapsing a LinearLayout. This animation depends on the MeasuredHeight property of the LinearLayout having a value greater than 0, but the value is always 0.

This is the code I'm using:

```
    public void Collapse()
    {
        var v = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layoutBranding);
        int initialHeight = v.MeasuredHeight; // always 0!!

        var a = new MyAnimation(v, initialHeight);

        a.Duration = (int)(initialHeight / v.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
        v.StartAnimation(a);
    }
```

Where MyAnimation is defined as:

public class MyAnimation : Animation
    {
        private readonly View _view;
        private readonly int _initalHeight;

```
    public MyAnimation(View view, int initalHeight)
    {
        _view = view;
        _initalHeight = initalHeight;
    }

    protected override void ApplyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
    {
        if (interpolatedTime == 1)
        {
            _view.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }
        else
        {
            _view.LayoutParameters.Height = _initalHeight - (int) (_initalHeight*interpolatedTime);
            _view.RequestLayout();
        }
    }

    public override bool WillChangeBounds()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the collapse in oncreate?

Comment: No, it's in OnResume.

Comment: Try to put this in onWindowFocusChanged . http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);


int initialHeight = v.MeasuredHeight;
```

Comment: Great! You can do it like this too... `view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);`  
`int initialHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();`

Answer (score 1):

Try to measure the height and width of the view in -

```
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(hasFocus)
        {
            // Get the height and the width of the view 
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1. All the other answers rely on the View being a custom one (where you have to extend LinearLayout). This should measure any of your visible views, custom or otherwise, at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Until the View has actually laid out (just before rendering), it will always have a height and width of 0

If you measure the height in `onMeasure` or `onLayout` (I think), then it should have a non-zero height

Comment: Do you mean `AddOnLayoutChangeListener`?

Comment: Nope I was suggesting extending the view that the OP is using, then overriding one of those methods